# which is better wcf or dll for a web application which will be used as a part(integrated) of many project?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, web-applications, dll

i have a project (Web Application) in c# like shopping cart and i have to build it in such a way it can be integrated in any other project to decrease work load.
so the functions of it can be used in best,secure and faster.
So what should i prefer **WCF or DLL's**(Class files.)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use WCF you will get a set of webservices that need to be hosted and can be called from one or multiple shopping systems. 
Such a service layer would be a nice idea if you can have multiple shopping systems that share their backoffice. The service layer can then be reused for multiple shopping applications.

If that's not the case and you want to only use reuse basic functionality, like a shopping card or a Product item, then you're not talking about sharing a whole service layer but about reusing several classes. A shared dll would then be more appropriated.

Another thing to keep in mind, is that if you design your solution with a service layer you can always quite easily decorate it with WCF attributes to turn it into a WCF service. The consuming code will not notice this.

So it depends on the amount of code you want to reuse and if the new applications can reuse it out of the box, or if they have to make modifications to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I Think i will go for wcf

Answer (score 0):

It depends, check the following points and decide yourself:

DLL will give you following advantages
1) Far better performance than WCF
2) output security, so if you don't want everybody to use your wcf function you can go for DLL

WCF has following advantages
1) Available from everywhere (online), no need to add DLL on every project , thus it decrease the size of your product.
2) WCF function call implementation would be almost same for any project
3) These methods can be called from Javascript (Web project) easily.
4) You can host your WCF application to any dedicated or dependent server.

After deployment if you want to make changes in logic , you can prefer WCF as you don't have to callback all the shopping cart sites and update each site with new DLL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I Think i will go for wcf. your answer was satisfactory but @Wouter de Kort gave me proper explanation relative to my problem. any ways thanks your answer help me to distinguish both and choose one

Answer (score 0):

I do prefer WCF service for a web application rather than dll's. Because they can be accessed through javascript. Can updated very easily. Services can be hosted on any dedicated server.